# Trying to load a view in an existing codeigniter application, need advice on the errors Im getting

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just started working on a codeigniter application.

The project is simple I just need to create a view and grab some data from a database.

However I keep getting these error when I try to access the view.

I am not sure what these errors mean.

Here is my code I use to load the view in the default controller class, its a separate function from the index function in that class.

```
function watchlist(){
            $this->load->view("watchlist_view");
        }
```

Here is how I am accessing the view in my browser.

```
localhost/watchlist/index.php/home/watchlist
```

Here are the errors Im getting.

```
    A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: session_start(): open(C:/xampp/session_data/localhost\sess_v4oapdmdqjq0s7b1i5j8mb8u95, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)

Filename: helpers/session_helper.php

Line Number: 18


Fatal error: Call to undefined method Home::load() in C:\xampp\htdocs\watchlist\application\controllers\home.php on line 23

Warning: include(application/errors/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\watchlist\system\libraries\Exceptions.php on line 163

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'application/errors/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\watchlist\system\libraries\Exceptions.php on line 163

Warning: include(application/errors/error_php.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\watchlist\system\libraries\Exceptions.php on line 163

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'application/errors/error_php.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\watchlist\system\libraries\Exceptions.php on line 163
```

Constructor Home Code

```
class Home extends Controller
    {

        var $ministry_name = "Security";

        function Home()
        {
            parent::Controller();
        }

        function index()
        {
            Removed local redirect. All sites will now redirect to main site
            //Added a check to see if the user is still logged in.  If so, remain on the site.
            if (!$this->authorization->checklogin())
            {
                header('Location: http://mainsite.org/');
                exit;

            }
            else
            {
                redirect("/home/main");
                exit();
            }

        }

        function watchlist(){
            //Loads watchlist view
            $this->load->view("watchlist_view");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

See https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#constructors. Here you should extend `CI_Controller` instead of `Controller`, and you may use a general constructor `__construct()` and `parent::__constructor();` instead of the old same-name style.

Comment: Ok I'm going to try this. Thanks